# iOS Build working in simulator but throwing error while archiving and running on real device

Tags: ios, macos-mojave, xcode10.1

I'm using xcode 10.1, macOS "Mojave" and my project is in swift 4.0. I am able to run the application on device but I can't archive. I have tried many solutions but nothing worked and now I'm stuck.

This is the error it is showing, when I click on the error in the project Navigator, the Xcode crashes. Can someone please tell me what could be the reason?

`linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

[image]

Comment: Have you tried deleting the derived data and cleaning?

Comment: Could you please tell us what solutions you've tried?

Comment: 1.Cleaning the derived data

Comment: 2.Build Active architecture to yes and No tried both 3. Changed workspace settings to both legacy and new build system. Every time I faced a new issue while trying above solutions. But the same project is working in another Mac os High Sierra xcode 10.1